# return an iterator from a method

Tags: c++, iterator, type-conversion, c++98

I am porting some old code. at moment I am stuck with C++ 98 standard.
I have this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

class ClassPointPrediction {

};
class ClassBuildPointPosition
{
    typedef vector<ClassPointPrediction> ClassPointPredictionContainer;
        const ClassPointPrediction* const currentPrediction() const;
private:
ClassPointPredictionContainer::iterator CurrentPoint;
};

const ClassPointPrediction* const ClassBuildPointPosition::currentPrediction() const
{

    return  CurrentPoint;
}

int main() {

cout<<"test\n";
    return 0;
}
```

ADDED:
The usage of the method is:

```
const ClassPointPrediction*  currentPrediction = pointPositions->currentPrediction();
```

and of course the iterator is already initialised:

```
CurrentPoint = PointPredictions.begin();
```

Trying to compile I receive

```
In member function ‘const ClassPointPrediction* const ClassBuildPointPosition::currentPrediction() const’:
/tcenas/home/iarnone/workspace/predictionstar/main.cpp:33:13: error: cannot convert ‘std::vector<ClassPointPrediction>::iterator’ {aka ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<ClassPointPrediction*, std::vector<ClassPointPrediction> >’} to ‘const ClassPointPrediction* const’ in return
     return  CurrentPoint;
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

how to correclty return that iterator?
should I initialize like this before return?

```
ClassBuildPointPosition::currentPrediction() const
    {
        const ClassPointPrediction* temp;
        return  CurrentPoint;
    }
```

Comment: Make the return type of the function `ClassPointPredictionContainer::iterator`?

Comment: @NathanOliver Probably `const_iterator`.

Comment: Whoever wrote the old code made invalid assumptions about implementation details. Old implementations of the standard library sometimes implemented vector iterators as plain pointers. This was never standard or portable, and you should fix that bug by using the appropriate type.

Comment: You may be confusing pointers with iterators. A pointer is compatible with the requirements of an iterator, so a pointer *could be* an iterator. For example for an array. But `std::vector`'s iterator type isn't necessarily a pointer. But it's also possible to return a pointer to a specific element, though that pointer might not be a valid iterator for the container. It isn't clear to me if you are trying to return an iterator for the range, or a pointer to the element.

Comment: yes, you are totally right. the issue is that the old sun compiler is so different with my GNU version. I am trying to not modify the old code but in this case i think I will change the return type. they wrote a method to access the current iterator...it's a mess

Answer (score 2):

You've specified that the return type of the function is `const ClassPointPrediction*`. The type of the iterator is `ClassPointPredictionContainer::iterator`. The type of the iterator isn't (necessarily convertible to) `const ClassPointPrediction*`. In order to return an object of type `ClassPointPredictionContainer::iterator`, you should specify that the return type is `ClassPointPredictionContainer::iterator`, rather than specifying the return type being something else such as `const ClassPointPrediction*` for example.

That said, you may want to return `ClassPointPredictionContainer::const_iterator` instead. Like this:

```
ClassPointPredictionContainer::const_iterator currentPrediction() const;
```

---

> ```
> ClassPointPredictionContainer::iterator CurrentPoint;
> ```

This variable is default initialised. If `ClassPointPredictionContainer::iterator` is trivially constructible - which it may be - then it has an indeterminate value. In such case, you must not read its value, such as for example as you do here:

> ```
> return  CurrentPoint;
> ```

If you do this, the behaviour of the program will be undefined. To fix this, properly initialise the iterator that you return.

Comment: the iterator is not initialised because it is a method to get the actual value of the iterator. it's used as const ClassPointPrediction*  currentPrediction = PointPositions->currentPrediction();

Comment: @Apollo17 `the iterator is not initialised because it is a method to get the actual value of the iterator.` I really don't follow what you are trying to say. You mustn't return the value of something that isn't initialised.

Comment: the iterator is already initialised in another place. In that method I need only to access to it. They builded a get() method in order to access to it

Answer (score 1):

This function

```
const ClassPointPrediction* const ClassBuildPointPosition::currentPrediction() const
{
    ClassPointPredictionContainer::iterator CurrentPoint;

    return  CurrentPoint;
}
```

in any case does not make a sense because it returns uninitialized variable.

Many early implementations of the iterator of the class template `std::vector` use ordinary pointers to elements of the vector as iterators.

You could rewrite the function for example the following way

```
auto ClassBuildPointPosition::currentPrediction() const
{
    ClassPointPredictionContainer::const_iterator CurrentPoint;

    return  CurrentPoint;
}
```

Or the following way

```
    ClassBuildPointPosition::ClassPointPredictionContainer::const_iterator
ClassBuildPointPosition::currentPrediction() const
{
    ClassPointPredictionContainer::const_iterator CurrentPoint;
    
    return  CurrentPoint;
}
```

Comment: yes, you are right, the initialization is made in another point that I skipped. I can't use the auto type because I am using the old standart C98. yes, I think I need for fure change the return type

Comment: @Apollo17 See my appended post.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I missed the deference operator, so I did like this:

```
if (CurrentPoint != PointPredictions.end())
  {
    return &(*CurrentPoint); // Returns the address to the element pointed by the iterator for ClassPointPrediction*
  }
```

It worked fine. thank you all.